# Apache Rewrite Rules - Path Style

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am coming from the IIS world to Apache and would appreciate some help on the rewrite rules.

I want this relative path:

```
/index.php?go=order&id=12345
```

to be rewritten as:

```
/go/order/id/12345
```

Also, if there are more parameters, they should be converted to path format:

```
/index.php?go=order&id=12345&action=process
```

becomes

```
/go/order/id/12345/action/process
```

How do I achieve this please? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your vhost config:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Start converting query parameters to path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/%1/%2?%3 [L]

# done converting, remove index.php and redirect browser
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite paths to query strings
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*) /$3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

# No more path, rewrite to index.php
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [L]
```

These rules will make it so if you type in a URL like `http://yourdomain.com/index.php?a=b&1=2&z=x` in your browser, the browser will get redirected to `http://yourdomain.com/a/b/1/2/z/x`. When the clean looking URL gets requested, the 2nd set of rules internally rewrites it back to `/index.php?a=b&1=2&z=x`. If you want to put these rules in an htaccess file (in your document root), you need to remove all the leading slashes in the `RewriteRule`'s. So `^/` needs to be `^` in the last 3 rules.

Note that if you simply go to `http://yourdomain.com/index.php`, without a query string, nothing gets rewritten.

Comment: Great! Now how do we check if the given path is not an existing directory or file? Static resources are not being loaded with this.

Comment: Thanks Jon! You taught me something new today! :)